# Django/Jinja - passing variable to button from textarea

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I would like to pass whatever the user input in the text area to the button to open a new page as shown in the graph.

How should I create (set?) the variable "{{ analysis_id }}"?

Thank you!

[Please check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJLJc.png)

Text area:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="geneid">Input sequence (Amino acid or Nucleotide) or Gene ID </label>
<textarea name="geneid" id="geneid" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
```

The button:

```
<button onclick="location.href='/analysis/{{ analysis_id }}';" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire approach is mistaken. You don't pass data to a button. You shouldn't have that onclick function at all; instead, wrap both textarea and button in a form element. Then the form will be submitted to a view, from where you can access the data via the request and pass it to the next template.